# How to scroll lock in a bash terminal on Xubuntu 18.04?

Tags: shortcut-keys, scrolling, xfce4-terminal

During processing, I want to be able to disable (and enable again) auto scroll down to newest output so that I can examine the output before.

Terminal software version: `xfce4 0.8.7.4`

Comment: duplicate of: https://askubuntu.com/questions/388956/prevent-xfce-terminal-from-scrolling-with-output - did not find it because I was thinking of the "scroll lock" key, but how it is implented it's fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> During processing, I want to be able to disable (and enable again) auto scroll down to newest output so that I can examine the output before.

I don't know whether what you want is possible "during processing", but *before* issuing a command, you can change the terminal's preferences via `Edit` > `Preferences` as seen in the image below.

[image: Scrolling in Xubuntu's terminal]

Most probably, just increasing the `Scrollback` value from the default should suffice. Going overboard may be an issue if you have limited RAM.

In case, you need a keyboard "toggle" to start and stop scrolling during a process running in the terminal, I'm not sure one exists at least in Xubuntu 18.04.